# How to listen emit event in parent component in vue3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I want to pass event from child comment to parent.
I did same thing in vue2 but i don't know how to that in vue3.

This one is child component setup method.

```
      setup(props, { emit }) {
            const router = useRouter();
            const form = ref(
                {
                    email: "ajay@gmail.com",
                    password: "123456789",
                    isLoading: false,
                },
            );
            const user = ref("");
            const error = ref("");

            function login() {
                User.login(this.form).then(() => {
                    emit('login', true);
                   // this.$root.$emit("login", true);  -- vue2

                   localStorage.setItem("auth", "true");
                   router.push('/dashboard');
                })
                .catch(error => {});
            }

            return { form, login, user, error};
       }
```

from here emit **login** method and i want to listen in parent comment.

this is parent component,  **emit.on** method not working here

```
  setup(props, { emit }) {
        const router = useRouter();
        const state = reactive({
            isLoggedIn: false,
        });

        onMounted(async () => {
            emit.on("login", () => {   // `vue2` this.$root.$on("login"`
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
            });
          
        });
```

Comment: you need to read this https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#custom-events

Comment: `<child-component @login="parentLogin"></child-component>`

Comment: Thanks for answer. @KamleshPaul
but here in my case i not declared  child component in parent component. (like  `<child-componen></child-componen>`.  im using `router-link` to go child component.
Any idea how to handle emitted event without declared child component ?.

Answer (score 2):

In parent component you should add a handler for that emitted event :

```
<child @login="onLogin"></child>
```

```
 setup(props, { emit }) {
        const router = useRouter();
        const state = reactive({
            isLoggedIn: false,
        });
 
   function onLogin(){
      state.isLoggedIn=true,
    }

   return{state,onLogin}

}
```

Or make a composable function named `useAuth` in separate file :

```
import {reactive} from 'vue'

   const state = reactive({
            isLoggedIn: false,
        });
const useAuth=()=>{
  
   function onLogin(){
         state.isLogged=true;
    }
return {state,onLogin}
}

export default useAuth();
```

then import the function inside the two components :

child :

```
import useAuth from './useAuth'
....
      setup(props, { emit }) {
            const router = useRouter();
             const {useAuth} =useAuth();
         ....
      function login() {
                User.login(this.form).then(() => {
                    onLogin() //will call the nested function that set loggedIn to true
                

                   localStorage.setItem("auth", "true");
                   router.push('/dashboard');
                })
                .catch(error => {});
            }
```

in parent :

```
import useAuth from './useAuth'
....
  setup(props, { emit }) {
        const router = useRouter();
       const {state} =useAuth();
       //it replaces your local state
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
but here in my case i not declared  child component in parent component. (like  `<child></child>`.  im using `router-link` to go child component.
Any idea how to handle emitted event without declared child component ?.

Comment: actually my parent comment is `Navigation` (there is login,register, logout, dashboard manu).
so i want to hide login/Register menu after login user & show logout / dashboard menu.

Comment: are you using vuex in your project?